# Loop in Excel VBA

Tags: loops, excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a logic in place, but no idea as to how to execute/code it in Excel. The logic is below:

At office, I need to find out the value of many old articles based on their purchase value and age. I don't want to use VDB or other inbuilt functions.

In my spreadsheet:

```
A1 = "Table" (Name of the article)  
B1 = "01/01/2005" (Date of purchase in MM/DD/YYYY format)  
C1 = "1000" (Purchase value)  
D1 = "=DATEDIF(B1,TODAY(),"Y")" (Gives the age of article in years)  
E1 = "20" (Percentage depreciation for first year, which varies based on article)  
F1 = "=C1*10%" '(Depreciated value should not be less than 10% of purchase value)
```

Now, in `G1` I want to calculate the depreciation value of article "`A1`" with purchase value "`C1`" for "`D1`" number of years, @ flat "`E1`"% for first year and 10% for subsequent years.

```
H1 = "=C1-G1" (Value of the article after depreciation)  
I1 = "=IF(H1<=F1,F1,H1)"
```

Please help me with a macro or formula to loop and find out the value of `G1`.

Also, I want to apply this to "n" number of rows since there are "n" number of articles.

**EDIT**

@[assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829571/assylias) Thanks for enlightening me about [SO policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/179508), putting me to work for myself to find the answer.

After some 30 min of googling followed by trial and error, I successfully wrote a macro to do what I wanted. Here it goes:

```
Sub DepVal()
'
' DepVal Macro
' Macro by Prashanth JC
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'
fYear = 0
dVal = 0
tYear = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3)
purVal = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4)
depFirst = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2)
depOther = 10

If tYear >= 1 Then
    Do
        If fYear = 0 Then
            dVal = purVal - (purVal * depFirst) / 100
        Else
            dVal = dVal - (dVal * depOther) / 100
        End If

        fYear = fYear + 1

    Loop Until fYear = tYear

    ActiveCell.Value = dVal

Else
    ActiveCell.Value = purVal

End If

End Sub
```

Finally, I formatted the G1 cell to a Number with Zero decimal place. Everything works perfect now!

Thanks again, SO and [assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829571/assylias)!

Comment: If you are familiar with SO then you won't be surprised to be asked: What have you tried?

Comment: Since I don't know anything about MACROS, haven't given it a try. My Excel knowledge is only about + - * /. The IF() statement I found on Google.

Comment: Somebody might help you but [you are supposed to try before asking and you can't expect someone to write the code for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/179508).

Comment: @assylias Thanks for your comment. I have found the answer myself but unable to post it here until next 8 hrs since my reputation is less than 100. Will post the macro I wrote in the next 8 hours.

Comment: I have edited my question, instead! :)

Comment: +1 your good attitude, willingness to learn and accept correction. Glad you figured it out too

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a macro, it's simple math.

Assuming that your percentage (in `E1`) is stored as `.2` (for 20%), not actually `20`, this formula would work:

```
=MAX(F1,C1*(1-E1)-(C1*0.1*(D1-1)))
```